# Docker: Running multiple applications VS running multiple containers

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, jboss, docker, wildfly

I am trying to run `Wildfly`, `Jenkins` and `Postgresql` in `Docker` container(s).

As far as I could understand from articles I've read, the Docker way is to have each application run in a different container.

Is my assumption correct or is it better to have only one container containing these three applications?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the basic philosophy behind docker is to run one service per container. You can run whole application inside a container, but I don't think that will go well with the way docker work. Running different services in different containers gives you more flexibility and a better modularity for your app.

Comment: in the FAQ you will find "How do I run more than one process in a Docker container?

Any capable process supervisor such as http://supervisord.org/, runit, s6, or daemontools can do the trick. "